# Detecting Red and Blue Squares (beanbags) using Python and CV2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, detection

I am new to CV2 and I am looking for some high level guidance for an application. I am working on a program that can detect red and blue beanbags that are in the frame of the camera. I played around with the example code offered by openCV to detect blue colors and modified it slightly to detect red as well.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
    lower_red = np.array([-20, 100, 100])
    upper_red = np.array([13, 255, 255])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is (slightly modified) copied and pasted code from the OpenCV site. I am looking for the correct way to analyze the `res` numpy array of the dimensions `<460, 640, 3>` in order to detect that

1. I have red/blue objects(s) on my screen
2. Do something with this information such as `print(1 red and 2 blue squares detected)`

Image link: 
[Input, res and mask image of blue beanbag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnvg8.png)

Comment: Please, update your post with a sample picture and with the results you have so far.

Comment: I have just done so, please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Can you post the input image aswell ?

Comment: Done (ran out of screen space haha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to obtain two masks, one for red and the other for blue as:

```
mask_red = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
mask_blue = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
```

Now let's define a function which detects if given area in mask if above threshold for taking decision if the bean bags are present, for that purpose we will use [`cv2.findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html).

```
def is_object_present(mask, threshold):
    im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    # Find the largest contour
    largest_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x:cv2.contourArea(x))
    if cv2.contourArea(largest_contour) > threshold:
        return True
    return False
```

Now you call this method on both the masks, to get individual values if red bean bag or blue bean bag is present:

```
# Adjust this manually as per your needs
bean_bag_area_threshold = 5000
is_red_bean_bag_present = is_object_present(mask_red, bean_bag_area_threshold)
is_blue_bean_bag_present = is_object_present(mask_blue, bean_bag_area_threshold)

if is_red_bean_bag_present and is_blue_bean_bag_present:
    print "Both bean bags are present."
```

Comment: Thank you, great response. Would you be able to add a comment on what the following line is doing: 1.im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

Comment: Oh my bad, I have attached link to [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)